# How to show an image and hide it after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML="<img src='load.gif'>";
```

With javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

**Edit**: I realize, isn't this a bit *fake*? Shouldn't you hide a `load.gif` when the loading task is *actually* finished? Using them for decoration only makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery for it so code is more elegant. Otherwise you could use `setTimeout`

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML="<img src='load.gif'>";
setTimeout("div.innerHTML=''",5000);
```

Comment: if you minus please explain what is wrong with the code so I can improve.